# Проблема с обновой сайта с joomla 2.5 на joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla

Проблема с обновой сайта с joomla 2.5 на joomla 3.3.

Во время обновления вылетела ошибка. Теперь при открытии сайта белый экран.

> Ошибка HTTP 500

Answer (score 2):

Включите показ ошибок и поймите, что за ошибка.

1. Найдите в корне проекта файл **configuration.php**
2. Там в переменной `error_reporting` поменяйте значение с "default" на "maximum".
3. После этого откройте сайт, вы увидите сообщение об ошибке.

После того, как всё поправите, не забудьте вернуть значение `error_reporting` опять на "default".

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня встретился с такой же ситуацией. Причиной белого экрана и ошибок оказалось, просто не поддержка старых модулей и плагинов.

Решение было: просто тщательный перебор модулей и удаление или отключение не нужных. Все заработало.

Comment: Мммм... не то, чтобы "не ответ", но пожалуй пусть остаётся. Хотя подобных вариантов, что именно могло бы на сервере могут быть десятки, а правильнее всего - открыть лог ошибок и читать его внимательно.